# Compilation error in submitting a JAR file on SPOJ

Tags: java, jar

I am submitting a JAR file for the [TEST](http://spoj.com/problems/TEST) problem on SPOJ but getting a compilation error.

```
2
/bin/bash: line 5: mkdir: command not found
/bin/bash: line 6: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 7: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 8: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: No such file or directory
   zip warning: name not matched: META-INF

zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r tested.zip . -i META-INF)
```

The contents of my JAR file already contain META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file, so I don't understand the compilation error.

```
$ jar tf Main.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Main.class
```

Following is the JAVA code I used for creating the JAR file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String s;
                while (!(s=r.readLine()).startsWith("42")) System.out.println(s);
        }
}
```

Any help in the direction of resolving the compilation error would be appreciated.

Edit: I am creating the jar using the java archive tool.

```
jar -cfm Main.jar manifest Main.class
```

where manifest contains

```
Main-Class: Main
```

Comment: can u show us the path structure of the Main class and  from where you are try to create a jar ?@sidi

Comment: What do you mean by path structure? I have edited the question to include information on how I am creating the jar.

Comment: Are you  trying to create jar  from the src directory ? @sidi

Comment: I am creating jar in the same directory as the source file.

Comment: Where does the first block of code come from? Was it from a command that you ran? If so, what was the command? Was it from SPOJ? If so, consider reporting this to them as a bug - it appears that whatever is getting run there is broken and unable to find `mkdir`, and so the rest of it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try submitting the solution via the Java (Hotspot 8u) option instead of the JAR (JavaSE6) option. This worked in my case!

In any case, you should try to [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) your solution first to verify it works perfectly, then submit it to the SPOJ judge

Comment: I haven't tried this out, but I believe this should work. The question isn't relevant to me anymore but could be to others :-).

Comment: I'd like to add that support for JARs will be removed from Spoj soon. You should submit Java solutions.